# MySQL - ORDER BY and GROUP BY together

Tags: mysql

I am using an external DB and I have 3 important columns: **user_id, total_score, score_order**.

I would like to **get the total_score of each user**.

All the scores are always recorded, so I only need the last one. For this I need to use the **score_order** column.

This is what I am trying to do (using nested queries because I need to **combine ORDER BY and GROUP BY**):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY score_order DESC
) AS tmp_table GROUP BY user_id
```

But I get the error:

> '#1055 - Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and
>   contains nonaggregated column 'tmp_table.ranking_id' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by Can someone explain what
>   I am doing wrong?'

Comment: You can make simple query for this, why are you retrieving all data when using group by

Answer (score 1):

In the default GROUP BY mode, you may only select columns that are in the group by clause, or aggregations on columns.

So for example, this might work:

```
SELECT user_id, MAX(total_score), MAX(score_order) as score_order_max 
FROM `table` GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY score_order_max DESC;
```

It works with `user_id` because it is in the group by, and the other two columns are aggregates.

I think you don't need a double select because MySql isn't oracle.

Comment: SUM(total_score) is not a real total_score. The real total_score is the last record. This is why I cannot use SUM.

Comment: If the `total_score` is increasing (and never decreasing), `MAX` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You find out the latest score_order for each user with max-aggregate function. Then select the rows with matching user_id and score_order.

```
select m.user_id, m.total_score
from mytable m
  join (
    select user_id, max(score_order) as score_order
    from mytable
    group by user_id
  ) s on s.user_id=m.user_id and s.score_order=m.score_order
```